# Reference request for centralizer of a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

> **Definition**: Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{R}.$ Let $ext(X^*)$ be the set of extreme points of the
>   closed unit ball of the continuous dual space $X^*.$
>
> A continuous linear linear operator $T:X\to X$ is said to be a
>   **multiplier** if every point $p$ in $ext(X*)$ is an eigenvector for the adjoint operator $T*:X^*\to X^*.$ That is, there exists a function
>   $a_T:ext(X^*)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that  $$p\circ T = a_T(p)p$$ for all
>   $p\in Ext(X^*).$
>
> The **centralizer** of $X$, denoted $Z(X),$ is the set of all
>   multipliers on $X.$

To my knowledge, monographs which contains information on centralizer above are

[(Fleming and Jamison) Isometries in Banach Spaces: Vector-valued Function Spaces and Operator Spaces, Volume Two](https://www.crcpress.com/Isometries-in-Banach-Spaces-Vector-valued-Function-Spaces-and-Operator/Fleming-Jamison/p/book/9781584883869) and

[(Behrends) M-Structure and the Banach-Stone Theorem](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0063153).

One article that I came across containing centralizer above is [Aroujo's paper](https://www.theta.ro/jot/archive/2006-055-002/2006-055-002-005.pdf).

> **Question**: Does there exist any monograph, other than the two above, containing information on centralizer? If yes, may I know its
>   title?

I am interested to know more about centralizer stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at these as well:

*[On Centralizers of Banach Algebras](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40840-014-0011-2)*

*[Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces, Volume 2](https://www.elsevier.com/books/handbook-of-the-geometry-of-banach-spaces/johnson/978-0-444-51305-2)*

(I think all that the above contains relating to the centralizer can be found at [this preview](https://books.google.gr/books?id=-2LFp8aQ1_UC&pg=PA1166&lpg=PA1166&dq=centralizer%20banach%20space&source=bl&ots=nJgrjUZrUh&sig=VQyD8kAIGahETtF66x4wFovLfvw&hl=el&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=centralizer%20banach%20space&f=false))

*[Banach spaces with the Daugavet property, and the centralizer](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123607004466)*

*[Centralizers and H$*$ Algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102994731)*

The first is likely the most concise and extensive and its list of references will probably be equally helpful as you delve on the subject of centralizers in general.

Comment: In the handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces. Volume 2, I think that centralizer in the article you linked is not the same as what I want.

Comment: @Idonknow Yes, I believe you are correct. I included it as a general reference to centralizers, as you said "I am interested to know more about centralizer stuff".